# TypeError:can't multiply sequence by non-int of type float

Tags: python, typeerror

I tried to put the `float` and `int` inside my coding, but it still said "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type `float`"

```
PV = input("investment amout:")
r = float(input("rate:"))
n = int(input("year:"))
FV_conti = PV*(1+r)**n
import math
FV_diceret = PV * math.exp(r*n)
```

Comment: Which language is this? If it is python, then try `PV = int(input("investment amout:"))`

Comment: It is python.THANKS！I  figured it out.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Or is the comment by @RohithS98 what helped you? In the latter case the two of you please make an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that PV is a string and not a float. `input()` is [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) does not evaluate the input unlike in [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

You need to convert it into a `int`/`float`:

```
PV = int(input("investment amout:"))
```

If you multiply a string with an int, it performs concatenation. That is why multiplying by float does not make sense.

```
>>> PV = "123"
>>> PV*2
'123123'
>>> PV*2.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```